I'm using gmstrftime but it's obsolete for my php version
I have the following code snippet:
function generate_calendar($year, $month, $days = array(), $day_name_length = 3, $month_href = NULL, $first_day = 0, $pn = array()){
  $first_of_month = gmmktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
  $day_names = array();
  for($n=0,$t=(3+$first_day)*86400; $n<7; $n++,$t+=86400)
    $day_names[$n] = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%A',$t));
    $mes_pt = array('', 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');

    list($month, $year, $month_name, $weekday) = explode(',',gmstrftime('%m,%Y,%B,%w',$first_of_month));
    $weekday = ($weekday + 7 - $first_day) % 7;

    $title   = htmlentities(ucfirst($mes_pt[(int)$month])).'&nbsp;'.$year;

    @list($p, $pl) = each($pn); @list($n, $nl) = each($pn);
       if($p) $p = '<span class="calendar-prev">'.($pl ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($pl).'">'.$p.'</a>' : $p).'</span>&nbsp;';
       if($n) $n = '&nbsp;<span class="calendar-next">'.($nl ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($nl).'">'.$n.'</a>' : $n).'</span>';
       $calendar = '<table class="calendar">'."\n".
          '<caption class="calendar-month"><h1><center><strong>'.$p.($month_href ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($month_href).'">'.$title.'</a>' : $title).$n."</strong></center></h1></caption>\n<tr>";

        if($day_name_length){ 

           $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='black'><center><strong style='color: #FFFFFF'>Domingo</strong></th>";
           $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='black'><center><strong style='color: #FFFFFF'>Segunda</strong></th>";
           $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='black'><center><strong style='color: #FFFFFF'>Terça</strong></th>";
           $calendar .=  "<th bgcolor='black'><center><strong style='color: #FFFFFF'>Quarta</strong></th>";
           $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='black'><center><strong style='color: #FFFFFF'>Quinta</strong></th>";
           $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='black'><center><strong style='color: #FFFFFF'>Sexta</strong></th>";
           $calendar .=  "<th bgcolor='black'><center><strong style='color: #FFFFFF'>Sábado</strong></th>";

           $calendar .= "</tr>\n<tr>";
         }
                                                        
         if($weekday > 0) $calendar .= '<td colspan="'.$weekday.'">&nbsp;</td>';
}

I tried changing the following code $day_names[$n] = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%A',$t)); and list($month, $year, $month_name, $weekday) = explode(',',gmstrftime('%m,%Y,%B,%w',$first_of_month));
by the following code:
$day_names[$n] = datefmt_format('%A', $t);
list($month, $year, $month_name, $weekday) = explode(',', datefmt_format('%m,%Y,%B,%w', $first_of_month));

but I get the following error when running the code:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: datefmt_format(): Argument #1
($formatter) must be of type IntlDateFormatter, string given

an you help resolve it?

Check the manual about what arguments it expects. Right now, you're passing in a string as first argument, when it clearly states (both in the manual and in the error message itself) that it expects the first argument to be an instance of IntlDateFormatter

@M. Eriksson I also tried this: $fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('pt_PT',IntlDateFormatter::FULL,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,    'Europe/Lisbon', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, "%A"); and then I put it like this: datefmt_format($fmt, $t);, but it didn't work either. Can you provide an example?

fyi, each has been deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0. bgcolor on a <td> and <center> are also deprecated

A good question contains a proper explanation of what you're trying to do (what is the input data and what result do you expect from that input). Then you show the attempts you made so far (without any code that isn't relevant to the specific error/problem) and explain how it doesn't work (invalid result/potential errors/warnings etc) so we don't need to waste time suggesting something you already tried.

You should also avoid using @ in front of function calls. There might still be some places it's still necessary, but those are few. Since that symbol supresses error messages, it makes any side effect from an error super hard to find. You should make sure the data is valid before trying to use it.

I solved the problem this way:
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
   'pt-PT',
   IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
   IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
   'Europe/Lisbon',
   IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
   'EEEE'
);
$day_names[$n] = $fmt->format($t);

$fmt1 = new IntlDateFormatter(
  'pt-PT',
  IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
  IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
  'Europe/Lisbon',
  IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
  'm,Y,B,w'
);
list($month, $year, $month_name, $weekday) = explode(',',$fmt1->format($first_of_month));

And I updated this line of code
@list($p, $pl) = each($pn); @list($n, $nl) = each($pn);
for
$index = 0;
foreach ($pn as $key => $value) {
  if ($index == 0) {
     $p = $key;
     $pl = $value;

  }elseif ($index == 1) {
     $n = $key;
     $nl = $value;

  }
  $index++;
}

